# The largest second number

Tags: java

I searched everywhere for a solution to find the second largest number, but I got one solution in all sites, and it's wrong.

The code I found:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = { 1, 23, 47, 81, 92, 88, 52, 48, 56, 66, 65, 76, 71, 85,
                   49, 53, 56, 61, 65, 84 };
    secondLargeNumber(arr);
}

public static void secondLargeNumber(int[] arr) {
    int largest = arr[0];
    int secondLargest = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > largest) {
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = arr[i];
        } else if (arr[i] > secondLargest) {
            secondLargest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("second largest in array is:" + secondLargest);

}
```

The code works fine , but if I changed the input sequence to:

```
 int arr[] = { 11, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
```

the output will be:

```
second largest in array is:11
```

I really don't know what to do!

Comment: first sort the array - then loop

Comment: @Randy - Sorting the whole array to find the second largest number is overkill.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `11` is still the first largest, just that it has occurred twice. The second largest is definitely `10`.

Comment: try initializing secondlargest to 0 in case you are working with positive integers

Comment: I am confused, how do you find it without sorting? You need to check every entry against other entries.

Comment: @arynaq - You don't need to put the entire array into sorted order. You just need to go through it and keep track of the two highest entries seen so far.

Answer (score 7):

Just do:

```
else if (arr[i] > secondLargest && arr[i] != largest) {
    secondLargest = arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void secondLargeNumber(int[] arr) {
          int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
          int secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
          for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                 if (arr[i] > largest) {
                       secondLargest = largest;
                       largest = arr[i];

                 } else if (arr[i] > secondLargest && arr[i] != largest) {
                       secondLargest = arr[i];

                 }
          }
          System.out.println("second largest in array is:" + secondLargest);

   }
```

Comment: same, " second largest in array is:11"   it should be 10 !

Comment: @DuaaIsaa And initialize values with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from here:-

```
int largest = arr[0];
int secondLargest = arr[0];
```

Try to initialize your variables with the least number like this:

```
 int secondlargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
 int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

How about this:-

```
   int secondlargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter array values: ");
        int arr[] = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = input.nextInt();
            if (largest < arr[i]) {
                secondlargest = largest;
                largest = arr[i];
            }
            if (secondlargest < arr[i] && largest != arr[i])
                secondlargest = arr[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two additions:

1. as other posts have suggested != largest check
2. If both largest and secondlargest start off with same value, switch the secondlargest to a smaller value asap.

   ```
         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > largest) {
                      secondLargest = largest;
                      largest = arr[i];

                } else if (arr[i] > secondLargest && arr[i]!=largest) {
                      secondLargest = arr[i];

                }else if(largest==secondLargest){
                    secondLargest = arr[i];
                }
         }
   ```