# Searching for the second largest number in a file

Tags: java, file

Is there a way to find a second largest/second lowest number in a .txt file without using Arrays or sorting? I am able to find the largest/lowest number by using while(file.nextInt())... But that's, where I finished.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673676/the-largest-second-number

Comment: Please don't add Meta information to your question. You don't need to add "thanks", please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do what I think you do (aka read all the numbers and keep the bigger/smaller), why don't you keep the biggest/smallest and the second one?

For Example:

```
int bigger = 0 // or whatever you want to initialize it
int second = 0 // the same

while(file.hasNextInt()){
    int newNumber = file.nextInt();
    if (newNumber > bigger){
        second = bigger;
        bigger = newNumber;
    } else{
        if (newNumber > second){
            second = newNumber;
        }
    }
}

// at the end you have the biggest and the second one.
```

Would that work for you?
Of course this example is about finding the second bigger number, you could modify it to find the second smaller number easily.

This is  by the way not the best method to to this...